Telegram Bot Issue: Admin Messages Not Delivered to Users
I have created a telegram feedback bot but here problem is all commands like /ping /start /help /about are working perfectly even admin is receiving user messages who messages through this bot and message id in log but when admin try to reply back to the user messages they don't receive. [my github repository(]https://github.com/rhamza783/Tfb)
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf');

require('dotenv').config();

const fs = require('fs');



const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

const ownerId = process.env.OWNER_ID; // Bot owner's Telegram ID

const userIDsFile = 'user_ids.txt'; // File to store user IDs



// Load existing user IDs from the file (if any)

let userIDs = [];

if (fs.existsSync(userIDsFile)) {

  const data = fs.readFileSync(userIDsFile, 'utf8');

  userIDs = data.split('\n').filter((id) => id.trim() !== '');

}



// Register the /help command

bot.command('help', (ctx) => {

  ctx.reply('Hey, I am Hamza Younis. How can I assist you? Feel free to chat with me.');

});



// Register the /about command

bot.command('about', (ctx) => {

  ctx.reply('This is a Telegram bot created using Telegraf by Hamza Younis.');

});



// Register the /ping command with response time

bot.command('ping', (ctx) => {

  const startTime = Date.now();

  const args = ctx.message.text.split(' ').slice(1);

  const responseTime = Date.now() - startTime;

  let response = `Pong!\nResponse time: ${responseTime} ms`;

  if (args.length > 0) {

    response += `\nReceived parameters: ${args.join(', ')}`;

  }

  ctx.reply(response);

});



// Function to forward messages from users to the owner

bot.on('text', (ctx) => {

  if (ctx.from.id.toString() !== ownerId) {

    console.log(`Forwarding message from ${ctx.from.id} to owner.`);

    ctx.telegram.forwardMessage(ownerId, ctx.from.id, ctx.message.message_id)

      .then((forwardedMessage) => {

        console.log(`Message forwarded to owner with message ID: ${forwardedMessage.message_id}`);

        // Store the mapping of the forwarded message to the original sender's ID

        userIDs.push(ctx.from.id.toString());

        fs.writeFileSync(userIDsFile, userIDs.join('\n'));

      })

      .catch((error) => {

        console.error('Error forwarding message:', error);

        ctx.reply('There was an error sending your message. Please try again later.');

      });

  }

});



// Register the /broadcast command

bot.command('broadcast', (ctx) => {

  const broadcastMessage = 'Hello, this is a broadcast message from your bot!'; // Set your desired broadcast message

  userIDs.forEach((userID) => {

    ctx.telegram.sendMessage(userID, broadcastMessage)

      .catch((error) => {

        console.error(`Error sending broadcast message to user ID: ${userID}`, error);

      });

  });

  ctx.reply('Broadcast sent to all users.');

});



// Start polling

bot.launch();

